# node-schedule run job if missed

Tags: node.js, electron

Does node-schedule support running a job after a scheduled run is missed? Like Windows Task Scheduler's "run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" checkbox.

My electron app has a reminder feature, so it's crucial that if the app is closed when the reminder is supposed to run, it runs immediately the next time the app is started. And additionally, if more than 1 scheduled starts have been missed, only run once, I don't want multiple popups of the same thing.

In case node-schedule does not support it, what can I use?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, turns out they had this feature in the past, before version 1.0.0. So I'm using < 1.0.0 to solve it. https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/issues/157